# Does $\hat{x}$ always mean normalized version of a vector $x$?

Tags: statistics, bayesian

From [this article](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~levina/papers/deconvLevinEtalCVPR09.pdf):

> "...a maximum-a-posteriori
>   $(MAP_{x,k}^{\,\,\,\,\,1})$ estimation, seeking a pair $(\hat{x}, \hat{k})$ maximizing:
>   $$p(x, k\mid y) \propto p(y|x, k)p(x)p(k).$$

Are $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{k}$ the normalized version of vectors $x$ and $k$, having length $1$? If so, could someone explain me why this does make sense?

Comment: This is related to statistics, and $(\hat{x}, \hat{k})$ are not normalized-things but estimators, found by optimizing a given function. See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_a_posteriori_estimation

Comment: If $x$ is the observation variable then $\hat{x}$ denotes the predicted (or fitted) value.

Comment: Why do we write bayes's rule in this form and not like this: $P(A_n|B) \propto P(B|A_n) P(A_n) $

Comment: arbautjc @Stéphane-Laurant: Which books would you recommend to learn more?